# Mongoose find all in given list of queries

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

How do I find all the documents that matches a list of queries in Mongoose?

For example, a model Person looks like:

```
{
   name, 
   lastname,
   ...
}
```

If I need to find specific people like John Doe, Alice Lorem, Bob Ipsum, is there a find to do it in a single find() command?

Something like

```
Person.find([{name: "John", lastname: "Doe"}, 
    {name: "Alice", lastname: "Lorem"}, 
    {name: "Bob", lastname: "Ipsum"}]);
```

Help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`$or`](https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.0/reference/operator/query/or/) logical query operator is what you need.

```
Person.find({
    "$or": [
        {name: "John", lastname: "Doe"}, 
        {name: "Alice", lastname: "Lorem"}, 
        {name: "Bob", lastname: "Ipsum"}
    ]
})
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Query.or`](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-or):

```
Person.find().or([
  {name: "John", lastname: "Doe"}, 
  {name: "Alice", lastname: "Lorem"}, 
  {name: "Bob", lastname: "Ipsum"}
]).exec(...)
```